# Tensorflow - Get hidden layer output of an autoencoder

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

I have a stacked autoencoder that is structured like `500-250-100-50-100-250-500`. I now want to take out the 50-dimensional hidden layer and use it to classify my input data in 2 classes using a softmax layer.

That means I need my autoencoder to compress my 500-dimensional input vectors from my training dataset into 50-dimensional vectors and use it to train the softmax layer. In addition to that I also need the 50-dimensional hidden layer.

How I would get the hidden layer: `autoencoder.layers[3]`

But how do I get the compressed 50-dimensional vectors of the 500-dimensional input vectors? I would need to get the output of that hidden layer when using `autoencoder.predict(x_train)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have another output from a hidden layer, you can get the output and add it to a new model like this:

```
new_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=autoencoder.input, outputs=[autoencoder.layers[3].output, autoencoder.output])
```

Then you can get the predictions like this:

```
hidden_layer_pred, last_layer_pred = new_model.predict(x_train)
```

Comment: Why would I need the `autoencoder.output` in `tf.keras.Model`? Wouldn't `autoencoder.layers[3].output` suffice?

Comment: If you want both of them in a one model, you can do like this. But if just hidden layer is enough for you, yes you can.